# Fetch data from local API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I have a simple API with symfony, run on http://127.0.0.1:8000 and a React project who run on http://localhost:3000.

I want to get this :

```json
{"0":{"id":51,"nom":"Ouais","prenom":"ssdds","competences":{}},"1":{"id":52,"nom":"Ouais","prenom":"ssdds","competences":{}},"2":{"id":53,"nom":"Alexis","prenom":"un truc","competences":{}}}
```

URL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/collaborateurs

So, in react i do :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';

fetch('/api/collaborateurs')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(json => console.log(json))

class App extends Component {

    render() {
    return (<div className="App">
        <h1>Salope</h1>
    </div>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

but

```
console.log(response)
```

return :

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/collaborateurs", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/collaborateurs"
__proto__: Response
```

why url: "http://localhost:3000/api/collaborateurs" i want url: "**[http://127.0.0.1:8000**/api/collaborateurs"](http://127.0.0.1:8000**/api/collaborateurs%22)

if i change fetch('/api/collaborateurs') to fetch('http://127.0.0.1/api/collaborateurs') the console.log not working

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8000/api/collaborateurs`?

Comment: This could be a problem with a CORS Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. Please check your network tab in dev tools and look for the XHR Request. What does it say? Does it fail?

Comment: Pay attention to port numbers. `fetch('/api/collaborateurs')` will fetch from the current host which is the react app at _http://localhost:3000_. _http://127.0.0.1/api/collaborateurs_ doesn't include any port number.

Comment: The response of `fetch` function has to be converted either to text or json. Try `fetch('/api/collaborateurs').then( d => d.json() ).then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: add proxy to your package json

Comment: Thank you boys it work with http-proxy-middleware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Create React App` - Proxying API Requests in Development -- `setupProxy.js`

IP http://127.0.0.1:8000 = IP http://localhost:8000

People often serve the front-end React app from the same host and port as their backend implementation.

Such setup is not required. However, if you do have a setup like this, it is convenient to write requests like `fetch('/api/todos')` without worrying about redirecting them to another host or port during

To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`, for example:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

You can use this feature in conjunction with the `proxy` property in `package.json`, but it is recommended you consolidate all of your logic into `src/setupProxy.js`.

First, install `http-proxy-middleware` using npm or Yarn:

```
$ npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
$ # or
$ yarn add http-proxy-middleware
```

Next, create `src/setupProxy.js` and place the following contents in it:

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

How use to FrontEnd React?

```
fetch('/api/collaborateurs')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

### ALL API DOCS:

### https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

https://medium.com/@Pavan_/set-up-proxy-to-work-with-multiple-apis-in-create-react-app-be595a713eb2