# how to make http request at same origin from where front-end is serve to access a directory's file's JSON data in react.js

Tags: reactjs, https

front-end is served from `http://localhost:3000/`

I want to access the JSON data which is inside a directory's file

by sending HTTP requests at same-origin `http://localhost:3000/`

in React.js

is it possible to do that, if it is so, how?

Comment: why don't you just import the JSON? like the other script inside of the project?

Comment: @marzzy yah I can but i am just experimenting is it possible to do something like that or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have 2 solutions:

1. import the JSON file
2. fetch the JSON file from the project (like an external API) [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427633/fetch-data-from-local-api?rq=1) for more details about the implementations